# Any examples of analysis in time domain to extact information

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, time-frequency, denoising, time-series

I am sending a 20Khz signal from my phone and capturing all the signals while doing exercise above it. Here I have a signal of a person doing "[hand scissors exercise](http://www.top10homeremedies.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/scissors-exercise.gif)"

I am doing analysis on how many times has the person done the exercise. I am able to figure that out in the frequency domain. But, the time-domain signal is very noisy, is there any way to extract any information in the time-domain from the existing signal that I have ?

**The FFT analysis of the signal is attached below** : 
 [image: frequency domain of the signal]

The raw signal in the time-domain is given below, is there anything that can be done on this :

(Y -axis is the energy of the signal) 
(X-axis is the number of frames in the wave signal)

[image: Time domain of the raw signal]

Comment: You have not specified what signal you have captured, what does the y axis represent?

Comment: @PAK-9 : I will modify the question and update it.

Comment: @hypfco : Can you provide me with a mail address to send the signal ?